Tkinter button not automatically updating when using .config
.config() doesn't update self.execute_rando_button state until after I forget then place it again. Obviously it's great that it works, but doing it that way feels like I'm cheating what would be the 'proper way' to do thing
I want to make a button that stays greyed out until every optionmenu is filled
But if i remove .pack_forget then place it again, the config won't change anything and the button will remain greyed out
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):

        self.title_label = tk.Label(root, text="Welcome to the Pokemon Team Randomiser")

        self.checkbox_header = tk.Label(root, text="Allow?")

        self.help_button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="?", command=help_callback)
        self.help_button_1.config(width=2, height=1)

        self.team_count_label = tk.Label(root, text="Team amount:")
        self.team_count_label.place(x=30, y=40)
        # label for the menu
        self.team_amount_options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
        self.team_amount_set = StringVar(root)
        self.team_amount_set.set(def_text)
        self.team_amount_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.team_amount_set, *self.team_amount_options, command=ta_callback)
        self.team_amount_menu.config(width=20)

        # selects amount of pokemon

        self.game_options = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"]
        self.select_game_label = tk.Label(root, text="Select game")
        self.select_game_label.place(x=30, y=90)
        self.game_option_selected = StringVar(root)
        self.game_option_selected.set("Red")
        self.game_choice_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.game_option_selected, *self.game_options,
                                              command=sg_callback)
        self.game_choice_menu.config(width=20)
        #
        self.starter_options = ["Yes", "No"]
        self.starter_select_label = tk.Label(root, text="Guarantee Starter?")
        self.starter_select_label.place(x=30, y=140)
        self.starter_option = StringVar(root)
        self.starter_option.set(def_text)
        self.starter_button = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.starter_option, *self.starter_options, command=ss_callback)
        self.starter_button.config(width=20)
        # starter select button
        self.typing_options = ["Free Typing", "No Same Primaries", "No Same Types"]
        self.typing_mode_label = tk.Label(root, text="Types allowed")
        self.typing_mode_label.place(x=30, y=190)
        self.typing_option = StringVar(root)
        self.typing_option.set(def_text)
        self.typing_mode_button = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.typing_option, *self.typing_options, command=tm_callback)
        self.typing_mode_button.config(width=20)

        self.evo_options = ["Final Evoloutions only", "Anything goes"]
        self.evo_stage_label = tk.Label(root, text="Allow Pre evoloutions")
        self.evo_stage_label.place(x=30, y=240)
        self.evo_option = StringVar(root)
        self.evo_option.set(def_text)
        self.evo_stage_button = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.evo_option, *self.evo_options, command=es_callback)
        self.evo_stage_button.config(width=20)

        self.trade_options = ["Allow trading", "Don't allow trading"]
        self.trade_evo_label = tk.Label(root, text="Allow trade only mons")
        self.trade_evo_label.place(x=30, y=290)
        self.trade_option = StringVar(root)
        self.trade_option.set(def_text)
        self.trade_evo_button = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.trade_option, *self.trade_options, command=te_callback)
        self.trade_evo_button.config(width=20)

        self.execute_rando_button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate", state=getattr(Settings, "exec_flag"),
                                              command=main_loop)

        self.main_box = tk.Canvas(width=510, height=280, bg="white")

        self.main_box.create_line(170, 280, 170, 0, fill="black")
        self.main_box.create_line(340, 280, 340, 0, fill="black")
        self.main_box.create_line(0, 140, 510, 140, fill="black")

    def pack_attr(self):
        self.title_label.pack()
        self.checkbox_header.place(x=100, y=390)

        self.help_button_1.place(x=750, y=12)
        self.team_amount_menu.place(x=30, y=55)
        self.game_choice_menu.place(x=30, y=110)
        self.starter_button.place(x=30, y=160)
        self.typing_mode_button.place(x=30, y=210)
        self.evo_stage_button.place(x=30, y=260)
        self.trade_evo_button.place(x=30, y=310)
        self.execute_rando_button.place(x=700, y=370)

        self.main_box.place(x=250, y=50)

    def rando_button(self):
        self.execute_rando_button.config(state=getattr(Settings, "exec_flag"))

        self.execute_rando_button.pack_forget()
        self.execute_rando_button.place(x=700, y=370)

        # removes old button, replaces it with new one that is activated


# trad evos check + mutually exclusive mons. Have the check while list is being generated
def execute_button_flag():
    settings_list = ["team_amount", "starter_choice", "typing_mode",
                     "evoloution_mode", "trade_setting"]
    check_list = []
    #maybe remove as theyre picked
    for i in range(0, len(settings_list)):
        #print(f"i is {settings_list[i]}")
        x = getattr(Settings, settings_list[i])
        check_list.append(x)
    if None in check_list:
        setattr(Settings, "exec_flag", DISABLED)
        print("i settings value is none")
    else:
        setattr(Settings, "exec_flag", ACTIVE)

    check_list.clear()

    MainWindow().rando_button()
   



MainWindow().rando_button() creates a brand-new MainWindow object, including all of its widgets, and then configures its Button's state - rather than the Button that's already visible on your screen.

You have so many typos error such StringVar(root) should be self.StringVar(root) and should self.trade_option.set(root) instead of self.trade_option.set(def_text).

self.execute_rando_button.pack_forget() does nothing because self.execute_rando_button has never been packed.  Also did you check the value of getattr(Settings, "exec_flag") inside rando_button()?  Is it what you expect?
